# django custom Registration Form which inherits from "UserCreationForm"

Tags: django

I have a small question about Django so I have a custom Registration Form which inherits from "UserCreationForm" and therefore I use "fields" to define the fields I want to display. For this test just ("username", "email",). But when I go to see my form which is displayed "Password" and "Password confirmation" are also present. Wanting to understand, I therefore went to see the UserCreationForm class of django but this one has a Meta class which has fields = ("username"), so I don't really see why I have the passwords which are also present. I'm sorry the explanation is a bit laborious but I would like to understand so if anyone has a little explanation thank you very much.

My custom class:

```
class CustomSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ("username", "email",)
```

The UserCreationForm of django:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
password.
"""

error_messages = {
    "password_mismatch": _("The two password fields didn’t match."),
}
password1 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Password"),
    strip=False,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"autocomplete": "new-password"}),
    help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
)
password2 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Password confirmation"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"autocomplete": "new-password"}),
    strip=False,
    help_text=_("Enter the same password as before, for verification."),
)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username",)
    field_classes = {"username": UsernameField}

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD in self.fields:
        self.fields[self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD].widget.attrs[
            "autofocus"
        ] = True

def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise ValidationError(
            self.error_messages["password_mismatch"],
            code="password_mismatch",
        )
    return password2

def _post_clean(self):
    super()._post_clean()
    # Validate the password after self.instance is updated with form data
    # by super().
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password:
        try:
            password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
        except ValidationError as error:
            self.add_error("password2", error)

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Here is what it gives:

[Display of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnPgE.png)

Comment: Because there are `password1` and `password2` fields in the form. These do not have to be part of the `fields`. If you define a field object in the class, it will be a field of the form.

Comment: It makes not much sense to inherit from `UserCreationForm` if you do not want any password fields, since most of the logic is written to do exactly that: checking if the two passwords match and hashing the password.

Comment: No, in reality this form suits me rather well. But the problem is that passwords always come last. Let me explain if for example I want:
Username:
E-mail:
Password1:
Password2:
Newsletter checkbox:

Well my checkbox will place it above the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is that the `password1` and `password2` field are defined in the `UserCreationForm` class. The form fields do not need to be listed in the `fields` attribute: all field objects in the class are form fields.

A `ModelForm` will in essence add form field objects to the class, and thus automates that process, but any field object defined in the class is a form field, that is how a simple [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form) behaves, and a `ModelForm` is just a subclass of `Form`.

Based on your comment you want to reorder the fields. You can do so with the [**`.field_order`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.field_order):

```
class CustomSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    field_order = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'newsletter')
    
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'newsletter')
```